# Why does my training loss is so high? How can i fix it?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

i'm a newbie in this subject but i'm trying to build a neural network which should predict the remaining useful life (RUL) of a bearing from a time series of its vibrations. I have a training set with this informations:

horiz. acc. | vert. acc. | time elapsed | degradation percent. | RUL

1. time elapsed: it's the amount of seconds elapsed from the start of observation.
2. degradation percentage: it's the result of (END OF LIFE)/(time elapsed)
3. RUL: it's simply (END OF LIFE) - time elapsed

I reshaped this data in order to obtain batches of:

x1_train)

- 3 time series. Each time series has 2560 samples, each sample has 2 features.

x2_train)

- 3 time values. It's the time elapsed value at the end of each time series.

y1_train)

- 3 values of the RUL, one for each time series

y2_train)

- 3 values of the degradation percentage

So my input shapes are:

- x1_train ----->(-1,3,2560,2)
- x2_train ----->(-1,3,1)
- y1_train ----->(-1,3,1)
- y2_train ----->(-1,3,1)

this is the network:

```
input_acc = Input(shape = (3,2560,2))
t_elaps = Input(shape = (3,1))


hidden = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))(input_acc)
hidden = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(hidden)
hidden = TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling1D())(hidden)
hidden = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3))(hidden)


degr_perc = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),name="deg")(hidden)


lstm_out = LSTM(128, dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True)(hidden)
hidden = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([lstm_out, t_elaps])
rul_output = Dense(1,activation="relu",name='rul')(hidden)

model = Model(inputs = [input_acc, t_elaps], outputs =[rul_output,degr_perc])

model.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss =[losses.mean_absolute_percentage_error, losses.mean_absolute_error],metrics = ['mse','mae','mape','cosine'], loss_weights = [1.0, 0.3])

model.fit([x1_train,x2_train],[y1_train,y2_train],epochs=4000,batch_size=1)
```

I have a total amount of 7524 time series in my dataset, from 6 different bearings. Sadly loss starts from an extremely high value and decreases with epochs with a slow rate.

How can i fix that? It's a network problem or maybe some error in my data?

Comment: Your have a regression problem, while accuracy is for classification problems. You shouldn't really use accuracy at all here.

Comment: Thanks @MatiasValdenegro . I've updated my question because i still have high values for the loss, so that was just one of the problems :)